# Can I use custom styling for loading message on @react-google-maps/api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I'm using  @react-google-maps/api for my app and it works well so far, however, while the map is loading there is a very ugly text that says 'Loading...' displayed instead of a map and I was wondering if I can replace it with a proper loader or at least style the text?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzi73.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a `ReactNode` into the `loadingElement` prop.

```js
const Loading = <div /> // change to whatever

<LoadScript
  googleMapsApiKey={googleMapsApiKey}
  ...
  loadingElement={Loading}
>...</LoadScript>
```

[Example](https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/blob/b5252a596f5b757175d2833074148cf8d31cafc4/packages/react-google-maps-api-gatsby-example/src/components/google-maps.js#L66)

Comment: @Teuta Please accept this answer.